# netrw not open correctly, just open blank with noperm message

Tags: neovim, netrw

I am Neovim user and have serious problem with netrw

I find netrw has a bug

[image: 1st picture]

when trying to open the file, at first it only shows an empty buffer(1st picture), and right bottom corner, you can see `[noperm]` message, I can not figure out the meaning of it

when trying open twice(2nd picture), then netrw correctly open a file. It's kinda nervous to me... whenever I open file , I should open twice,. It usually occur when open a file from different directory

for example,

1. If first time I'm in `src/components/App.tsx`
2. then I want to open `src/tsconfig.json`(I mean path of directory changed),
3. then it open empty buffer not open actual content

[image: 2nd picture]
what is this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden Hello, thanks for welcome

Comment: Does this happen with `vim -u NONE` or `-Nu NONE`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Sorry too late, I test your command, but In this case, `:Explore`(for open netrw) is not working, it shows error `vim not an editor command explore` so I couldn't test anything.

Comment: Sorry, try `vim -Nu NORC` (I forgot that `NONE` skips plugins)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for correct command, but without config It still happens, I set `let g:netrw_liststyle=3` for tree style and empty buffer happen when open a file in another directory. 
I find this issue report, but I don't know It solved or not
[issue#3276](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3276)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the permission for others

```
sudo chmod o=r [filename]
```

Explanation: Change ownership of file permission for Others to read.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would be improved by an [edit] explaining what the command does and why changing the permission would affect how netrw functions.